# How can I change the default vibration pattern?

Tags: android, android-vibration

I want to replace the default vibration pattern of the system to my customized vibration pattern, how can i do it?

Comment: i want to change the pattern globally which is by default will be used by all applications.

Comment: I don't think you can. Maybe yes, but I guess only on rooted phones